# Pandas - Aggregating column value from another dataframe based on common column between 2 dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 different dataframes like so -

[image: DataFrame1]

and

[image: DataFrame2]

I need to add a column "Present In" to the first dataframe, that lists all the items in C that correspond to the K ID in the second dataframe. So, the first table should look something like -

[image: DataFrame1-r]

How can I do this using Pandas? Thanks! :)

Comment: Please try not to post screenshots in your answer when you want to share data. People who try to answer cannot copy anything from the pictures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will do `gruopby` with `df2` , the `map`

```
s=df2.groupby('K ID')['C'].apply(','.join)

df1['Present In']=df1['K ID'].map(s).fillna('')
```

Comment: was writing the same answer, but then use `merging`